# Square brackets after getElementsByTagName What are they used for?

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in C# and recently started studying JavaScript and met this situation. I was trying to get element by tag name like that

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

which didn't work. After a research in internet I found this

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
```

which worked. My question is what is the purpose of the square brackets?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName   search query: `getelementsbytagname mdn`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

The key here is the word **Elements**

This method can return zero, one or more elements in an array-like object called a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

The use of [0] is to find the first element in that list.

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
```

If there are no elements in that `NodeList` then element will be `undefined` and following code can check for that.

### Free Debugging Hint

If you ever have a value that you're not sure why it is behaving the way that it is do this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('script'))
```

and you'd have been able to see it wasn't a single element returned.

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list and `[0]` indicates the first element from the node list

Comment: It returns a node list, not an array.

Comment: A list is like an array

Comment: except that it has none of the array methods.

Comment: @Quentin if OP doesn't know what square brackets do... is it really the time to debate lists vs. arrays?

Comment: Yes, it's very important to note that it isn't an array, otherwise the OP will be back later with that question too.

Comment: @KevinB (and Quentin) -- and is StackOverflow going to be closed for business "later"?

Comment: I agree people need to know and make the difference between these two things. But if he's so basic he needs to find out about brackets from us -- lists and arrays will confuse him.

Comment: Maybe not, but telling him it is an array is incorrect. we don't have to explain what a nodelist is, just don't call a nodelist an array.

Comment: I'd go for saying it's an "array like" object -- so his curiosity can lead from here. What is an array on the one hand and why this object isn't an array but it is "array like" on the other hand.

Comment: Also... calling tomatoes a legume is not technically correct but for household purposes literally no grammar nazis are going to break into your house and spank you for calling a tomato a legume when it is in fact a fruit.

Comment: What! Tomato is a fruit now

Answer (score 3):

The function `getElementsByTagName` returns an "array like" object of type `NodeList` (an object which behaves similar to an array).

To access the first item in the NodeList that is the result of `getElementsByTagName`, you can use the `[0]`. (note that the index is 0-based).

Make sure you check on the `length` first though:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
if (elements.length > 0)
{
  var firstElement = elements[0];
}
```

Comment: No, it does not return an array.

Comment: @KevinB: You are right, corrected.

Comment: For the purpos of clarity I'd use the following wording: "getElementsByTagName returns an "array like" object of type NodeList (an object which behaves similar to an array).

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets is a standard way to access a specific index of an array.

Example:

```
var arr = [ "one", "two" , "three" ];
console.log( arr[ 1 ] ); // ouputs "two"
```

The `getElementsByTagName` function is able to return multiple elements in a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that have the specified tag, so using the square brackets lets you specify what elements to access.

**A `NodeList` is not an array**, but accessing the elements it contains is done in the same was as with an array. Using `[0]` indicates that you want to access the first element in the `NodeList`.